# Unable to fetch data from api in react

Tags: reactjs, sequelize.js

I am trying to fetch data from workable api and load data into my UI. But `items.map is not a function` error always trouble me to move forward.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: [],
        isLoaded: false,
        data: this.props.location.data
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log('user id profile ' + this.state.data);
    if (this.state.data != null) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/' + this.state.data)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    items: json
                }, () => {
                    console.log('Hi '+json);
                })
            });
    }
}
```

Here console log of 'Hi' also not get printed. My backend api as follows.

```
app.get('/api/stylist/:userId', (req, res) => {
User.findOne({
    where: {
        userId: req.params.userId
    }
}).then(user=> res.json({
    user: user
}))
})
```

`this.state.data` is also having a value. So where could I get wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your API returns an object (single user) but you are using it as if it were an array (`items: json`)

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('user id profile ' + this.state.data);
    if (this.state.data != null) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/' + this.state.data)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    items: [data.user] // wrapping w/ array should help
                }, () => {
                    console.log('Hi '+ this.state.items);
                })
            });
    }
}
```